# The model already has an element that has the same name

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I just created a new solution made up of two projects:

1. SQL Server 2008 Server Project
2. SQL Server 2008 Database Project

The Database Project has a Database Reference to the Server Project.  When I try to build the solution I get three errors:

```
Error   291 SQL04105: The model already has an element that has the same name
dbo.sp_scramble

Error   292 SQL04105: The model already has an element that has the same name
dbo.sp_scramble.@Table.

Error   293 SQL04105: The model already has an element that has the same name
dbo.sp_scramble.@Field.
```

Both the Server and Database project were created by using the "Importing Objects and Settings..." option.

Also, the Server Project alone, builds without errors.

I'm using the project templates that shipped with VS 2010.

I guess my question is what caused these errors?

**UPDATE:** I fixed the errors by renaming the stored procedure, still I wonder what caused the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the errors by renaming the stored procedure.

Comment: Good to know, but the cause of the issue would be far more useful.